# Removing duplicates and preserving order when elements inside the list is list itself

Tags: python

I have a following problem while trying to do some nodal analysis:

For example:

```
my_list=[[1,2,3,1],[2,3,1,2],[3,2,1,3]]
```

I want to write a function that treats the element_list inside my_list in a following way:

> -The number of occurrence of certain element inside the list of my_list is not important and, as long as the unique elements inside the list are same, they are identical.
>
> Find the identical loop based on the above premises and only keep the
>   first one and ignore other identical lists of my_list while preserving
>   the order.

Thus, in above example the function should return just the first list which is [1,2,3,1] because all the lists inside my_list are equal based on above premises.

I wrote a function in python to do this but I think it can be shortened and I am not sure if this is an efficient way to do it. Here is my code:

```
def _remove_duplicate_loops(duplicate_loop):

        loops=[]
        for i in range(len(duplicate_loop)):

            unique_el_list=[]

            for j in range(len(duplicate_loop[i])):
                if (duplicate_loop[i][j] not in unique_el_list):
                    unique_el_list.append(duplicate_loop[i][j])

            loops.append(unique_el_list[:])

        loops_set=[set(x) for x in loops]
        unique_loop_dict={}

        for k in range(len(loops_set)):
            if (loops_set[k] not in list(unique_loop_dict.values())):
                unique_loop_dict[k]=loops_set[k]

        unique_loop_pos=list(unique_loop_dict.keys())

        unique_loops=[]

        for l in range(len(unique_loop_pos)):
            unique_loops.append(duplicate_loop[l])

        return unique_loops
```

Comment: does it need to be a list? couldn't/shouldn't you use a set data structure as opposed to a list?

Comment: Also, Python does not use `;`.

Comment: @limelights : was playing with C# and Java before I visited python, the language I used 3 years ago for a short time. Thus got the habit of ;

Comment: @Yoel: I am outputting the list as the loops I get from nodal analysis and came far with it. Please suggest if think there is suitable data structure for this.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Thanks Steven. Can you please show me, in my code above, which variable declarations are redundant? I would be glad if you give some feedback about the clarity and some way to improve the above code.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades:  I was only pointing out that C#/Java conventions need to be abandoned when using another language.  There are no problems with respect to declarations.  I was just trying to convince you to jettison the use of semicolons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
my_list = [[1, 2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1, 3]]

seen_combos = OrderedDict()
for sublist in my_list:
    unique_elements = frozenset(sublist)
    if unique_elements not in seen_combos:
        seen_combos[unique_elements] = sublist
my_list = seen_combos.values()
```

Answer (score 2):

you could do it in a fairly straightforward way using dictionaries. but you'll need to use `frozenset` instead of `set`, as sets are mutable and therefore not hashable.

```
def _remove_duplicate_lists(duplicate_loop):
     dupdict = OrderedDict((frozenset(x), x) for x in reversed(duplicate_loop))
     return reversed(dupdict.values())
```

should do it. Note the double reversed() because normally the *last* item is the one that is preserved, where you want the *first*, and the double reverses accomplish that.

edit: correction, yes, per Steven's answer, it must be an OrderedDict(), or the values returned will not be correct. His version might be slightly faster too..

edit again: You need an ordered dict if the order of the lists is important. Say your list is

```
[[1,2,3,4], [4,3,2,1], [5,6,7,8]]
```

The ordered dict version will ALWAYS return

```
[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]
```

However, the regular dict version may return the above, or may return

```
[[5,6,7,8], [1,2,3,4]]
```

If you don't care, a non-ordered dict version may be faster/use less memory.